# How detect XSS on website?

Tags: security, xss

I need to verify the safety of my website. Do you know some tools for testing website safety i.e. sql injection, xss, .... ?

Can you recommend the best way to verify safety?

Comment: You don’t need to detect it, just apply best practices to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a question for Webmasters.SE or Security.SE rather than SO. But anyways...

There are many [freely downloadable website vulnerability testers](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/14-popular-web-application-vulnerability-scanners/). I personally have used https://www.netsparker.com/communityedition/ and it caught some SQL mistakes in code from our contractor.